# How did Ghost survive this in season 8 episode 3?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In season 8 episode 3 we see Ghost

> charging to the wights with the Dothraki and Jorah.

After a little while, we see that

> the Dothraki forces were almost wiped out by the wights. We see Jorah returning, but Ghost was no where to be seen.

In the next episode he's seen alive, did we ever get canon news on how he survived the battle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The same way the Dothraki did, presumably they either fled to the surrounding areas, carried on fighting up where they were "wiped out" or fled back to Winterfell. We do see some come back to Winterfell after all. Whilst David Benioff says the following in the Inside the Episode it is contradicted later on in the season.

> **David:** What they see is just the end of the Dothraki, essentially.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 8 Episode 3, "Inside the Episode"</sub>

However, later on we see that only around half of the Dothraki were actually killed.

> **Grey Worm:** Half are gone. *Grey Worm removes half of the Unsullied markers.*
>
> **Jon Snow:** The Northmen as well. *Jon Snow removes half of the Northmen markers.*
>
> *Yohn Royce removes half of the Arryn markers.*
>
> *Dothraki soldier removes half of the Dothraki markers.*
>
> [...]
>
> **Tyrion Lannister:** So if all are in agreement Jon and Ser Davos will ride down the Kingsroad with the Northern troops and the bulk of the remaining Dothraki and Unsullied. A smaller group of us will ride to White Harbor, and sail from there to Dragonstone with our queen and her dragons accompanying us from above.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 8 Episode 4, "The Last of the Starks"</sub>

It's not actually explained where they all were and what happened to them as far as I know but I think the above guesses are somewhat accurate. Lastly, Ghost has been known to wander and do his own thing, it's possible after losing his ear and being injured he just left and came back later on.

Comment: Did the producers say anything specifically about Ghost though?

Comment: @Termatinator I don’t believe so, I’m just rewatching the Inside the Episode to double check though.

Comment: Him and the Dothraki went for a sidebar off to the Wolfswood

Comment: He was far to clever, he was out on the left, charging away, Dothraki 1 to Dothraki 2, don't worry about the left flank, that ghost has mad skills......... 30 seconds later, where is ghost, the left flank has fallen, umm last I saw he was running off to bury a leg bone.

Comment: The writers don't know how Ghost got away, he just did .. There was zero thought behind that scene so I doubt they will ever explain anything in that season

Comment: @EricSSH No reason that should stop the rest of us.  Ghost probably has much better low light vision than the Dothraki.  He probably saw they were screwed before the horsemen, and turned tail just in time to escape with only the one lost ear; wights focused on horsies. Dothraki further back probably just threw their blades at the horde before turning back.  In the books the things are *way* more flammable than they are in the show, incidentally. The Dothraki, the flame pit, and the dragons would have easily incinerated the vast majority of the wights in short order with book-flammability.

Comment: "...presumably they either fled to the surrounding areas..." - What surrounding areas? The only people who could have conceivable flee to a surrounding area were the extreme right and left wings of the charge...but it doesn't appear that there was anywhere to even flee to.  Also, why would a Dothrako flee? He...got scared? (Which I suppose could happen, but would be out of character for them).